# Need a timestamp with microseconds as Decimal

Tags: python, datetime, microtime

Currently I'm using time.time() to create timestamps that include microtime. But primarily I'm comparing these against a decimal and time.time() returns a float.

Currently I convert the value from float to decimal when needed:

```
if type(stamp) == float:
        stamp = Decimal(format(stamp, '.15g'))
```

But I lose some precision when doing this of course. How else can I get a microtime decimal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass a `float` to the `Decimal` constructor directly:

```
d = Decimal(stamp)
```

CPython `float` uses C `double` that has more than enough precision to represent microseconds in the usual timestamp range.

`time.time()` and `datetime.utcnow()` may produce slightly different results. The latter is rounded to microseconds:

```
from datetime import datetime 
from decimal import Decimal

td = datetime.utcnow() - datetime(1970, 1, 1)
timestamp_microseconds = (td.days*86400 + td.seconds)*10**6 + td.microseconds
d = Decimal(timestamp_microseconds).scaleb(-6)
```

The result should be equal to `Decimal(time.time())` with microsecond precision.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize I could pass a float right to the Decimal constructor. Looks like that was added in 2.7. Awesome. However, I do get somewhat funny results:

Comment: Stupid 5 minute rule :) Thank you! I didn't realize I could pass a float right to the Decimal constructor. It looks like I've figured out my problem... My django model is created as a decimal to 6 places, and in some cases that is getting compared against the float I mentioned before. My issue is really with comparing the decimal that's been trunc'd to 6 places with a float that is just a float